# Finding the matrix of a rotation transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

The rotation transofrmation is defined as some composition of rotatation along the $x,y,z$ axes.

Assuming $T$ is a rotation transformation in $\mathbb{R}^{3}, 
v=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right), 
T\left(v\right)=\left(1,0,0\right)$

I need to find the matrix of $T$ according to the standard base.
I was trying to find a rotation through $y$ axis such as $S_{\phi}\left(v\right)\subseteq XY$  plane, where $S$ is rotation along $y$-axis.
Not sure if they meant $T$ is rotation along $z$-axis.
But I am not sure if that's how I handle this question.

Comment: There seems to be insufficient information; also the vectors you have given us seems to be transposes of what you intended.

Comment: @KannappanSampath: I find your second remark a bit pedantic: certainly there is nothing wrong with denoting an element of $\mathbb R^3$ by a triplet of real numbers. The habit of writing them vertically helps us remember how to operate by a matrix on a vector, but I would not advocate imposing the use of distinct versions of $\mathbb R^3$ to contain column vectors and row vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Your equations are insufficient to determine the rotation $T$. To see this, consider a rotation $R$ with axis $\left<v\right>$; if $T$ is any solution then so is $T\circ R$, since compositions of rotations are again rotations. (You can also compose on the right with rotations with axis $\left<T(v)\right>$, although this gives no *other* alternative solutions than those found by the first method.)

The axis of any rotation that solves this problem must lie in the reflection plane (perpendicular bisector) $H$ between the vectors $v$ and $T(v)$, since any point of the axis obviously stays at equal distances form the two. Moreover any line $l$ in $H$ and passing through the origin can be the axis of a rotation solving the problem. To see this, compose the reflection in $H$ with the unique reflection fixing both $l$ and $T(v)$ (i.e., reflection in the plane spanned by $l$ and $T(v)$). This composition is a rotation, and it sends $v$ to $T(v)$.

For instance, one gets a rotation by a minimal angle by choosing $l$ to be perpendicular to both $v$ and $T(v)$: the line spanned by $(0,1,-1)$. Compute the reflection in $H$ followed by the one in the plane spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ (the latter is simple: $(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,-z,y)$) to find a concrete solution.